# Split digits from strings and take the maximum

Tags: python, pandas, string, split

I need to extract only those digits which precede a letter in strings. For example 1A, 22C, 3C4, 10A, I want to get output as 1, 22, 3, 10 and then take maximum of it, which will be 22.

Comment: `df['col'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int).max()`.

Comment: In what form is your input? Is it a DataFrame or String?

Comment: It's a column in a dataframe

Comment: @QuangHoang does this ensure that only digits before letters are selected and not after it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to find digits which precede a letter e.g.:

```
from re import findall, I
s = "1A 22C 3C4 10A"
matches = findall(r"(\d+)[a-z]",s,I)
maximum = max(map(int,matches))
```

`findall` would find all the matches in string `s` which conform to the regex `r"(\d+)[a-z]"`. `\d+` matches one or more digit characters (0-9) and `[a-z]` matches a letter (note the `I` flag tells the regex to ignore case, so `[A-Z]` letters are also matched).

`map(int,matches)` converts all the matches to integers and `max` simply finds the largest value of those.

Comment: Simple, yet brilliant solution!